# After calling mediaplayer.stop() I can't start sound again. Interpret dev reference for me?

Tags: java, android, media-player

here are some quotes from the dev reference that after reading can't get my in game sound to work. Maybe you can help me?

"once in the Stopped state, playback cannot be started until prepare() or prepareAsync() are called to set the MediaPlayer object to the Prepared state again."

In my splash screen class I use the Media Player .create in order to locate the resource and prepare it. I then continue to play and stop it. I use .reset after I stop it.

ex.

```
private MediaPlayer mpSplash;
mpSplash = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.splashscream);
mpSplash.start();
mpSplash.stop();
mpSplash.reset();
```

In my game loop, in my character class I use create again on a new Media Player variable to load and prepare another sound. When I use Start my programs throws an error, so I try to manually prepare it before with .prepare and that shows a red line say IO error. I tried .prepareasync and that also didn't work.

ex.

```
private MediaPlayer mpBearHurt;
mpBearHurt =  MediaPlayer.create(cxt, R.raw.bear_hurt);
mpBearHurt.reset();
mpBearHurt.prepareAsync();
mpBearHurt.start();
```

Here is the link to the dev resources...
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html

In the end no matter how I swap around and try to prepare and reset and what not I can't get my program to not force close.

Thanks and I hope we can work together to fix this problem!

Comment: `mpBearHurt` is a new mediaplayer, it's not in a stopped state. The problem is whatever error you're getting when you call `mpBearHurt.start()`. Please post the error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Schwiz has got it. Unless you're streaming, you can usually just use `prepare()`. I would recommend not creating new instances all the time. Instead, you can just set the data source of the existing player and re-use it. For example:

```
MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
AssetFileDescriptor bearAfd = getResources().openRawResourceFd(R.raw.bear_hurt);
AssetFileDescriptor screamAfd = getResources().openRawResourceFd(R.raw.splashscream);

mp.setDataSource(bearAfd.getFileDescriptor(), bearAfd.getStartOffset(), bearAfd.getLength();
mp.prepare();
mp.start();

//then to set it to another one
mp.setDataSource(screamAfd.getFileDescriptor(), screamAfd.getStartOffset(), screamAfd.getLength();
mp.prepare();
mp.start();
```

Once you start making too many MediaPlayers, you're likely to run out of memory, or overwhelming the audio hardware, and you'll get a lot of seemingly random errors and crashes.

Answer (score 4):

If you call `prepareAsync` then you can't call `start` directly after it, you have to use the `OnPreparedListener` callback for when to call `start`. Alternatively you could just call `prepare` instead.

Comment: Why is it that it has problems with me calling prepare();?

Comment: @Kirk Becker the problem is you aren't calling `prepare` you are calling `prepareAsync` so when you call start the media player actually isn't ready yet.

Answer (score 0):

First comment - there is no relation between the two MediaPlayer objects.
(unless you are using the Audio focus - which doesn't seems to be the case here)

The problem lays in what is done in the second code exmaple.

- No need to call prepare while using the create method - look at http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html#mediaplayer
- Calling to reset() put MediaPlayer into idle state - you should call to setDataSource - look at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#State%20Diagram

This is how the second code should look like:

```
private MediaPlayer mpBearHurt;
mpBearHurt =  MediaPlayer.create(cxt, R.raw.bear_hurt);
mpBearHurt.start();
```

You can do what ever you want with the other MediaPlayer object, you can even keep him playing if you want :)